# In the film Jacob's Ladder, did Danny Aiello's character serve a specific purpose?

Tags: character, jacobs-ladder

This has always bugged me, because the movie (I believe) is supposed to take place in some sort of Purgatory.  Danny Aiello's character seems to be pivotal in that he's always offering guidance to Tim Robbins (Jacob).  But the movie (to me, at least) is so very confusing to begin with.

Has anyone seen this movie that can shed some light on it for me?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I saw it, but as I recall, Danny Aiello was kind of a guardian angel.  Several times he pulled Tim Robbins out of a tough spot and "realigned" him (got him back on the correct spiritual path).  The "realignments" hurt Tim, but Tim needed it.

Comment: If you could flesh this out, it might be a good answer. As it is, it's more of a comment.

Comment: I know. I was debating whether to include this as an answer or a comment, and I chose "answer" since it answers the question even though it's got hardly any details. I don't have time to research and flesh it out, so hopefully someone else will give the same answer but with details!